# scrollr.js animation happens on element only with position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

Hey guys i am new to Jquery and i was trying integrating the scrollr.js plugin in my website and came across the a difficulty , i have the following HTML :

```
<div  data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);transform:rotate(0deg);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);transform:rotate(360deg);" class="block"></div>
```

and the following CSS :

```
.block {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/g6ncjdm6/1/)

now with the above CSS , the animations don;t work , scrollr.js does't work , but when i apply the following CSS :

```
.block {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top:20px;
}
```

The animations and everything works fine .

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g6ncjdm6/2/).

i don't always want the position on my element to be fixed . how do i get the animations to work, without taking out the element from the normal flow of the document ??

I saw [this demo](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/docu/2.html) on scrollr.js .

But still can't get why my example does't work. , If somebody could explain why my example is not working . it would be of great help .

Thanks .

Alexander.

Comment: Do you need to scroll all page by this scrollr or just this text?

Comment: the situation could be improved if change .block position to the absolute

Comment: @kris , the red box does't animate , see 1st fiddle .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g6ncjdm6/3/ it animates, but flows to the top

Comment: @kris can u make my 1st fiddle work ?? or tell me why the animation does't happen ?

Comment: @kris , i think i got my answer in the below answer. ty for ur help and time

Comment: it works, but on the 'relative' position, if you will scroll slowly and when you will attempt to the 'box', you see how it spins. The other question, where the box will be located? fixed inside some wrapper, or inside window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72985/discussion-between-alexander-solonik-and-kris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first animation does work. You probably don't see it because it starts animating as soon as you start scrolling and when you scroll to the image, animation is already done. Try making your screen height bigger, or remove some text at the beginning.

If you want animation to start when the item actually appears on the screen, take a look at [documentation](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#relative-mode-or-viewport-mode).

Try to change `data-0` to `data-bottom-top` and `data-500` to `data-center`.